# How to do Join on 3rd data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe (5ml rows) each, DF1 & DF2. Each row in DF1 corresponds to row in DF2 at same index.

DF1:-

```
miliSecDF.iloc[:,list(range(1, 81, 2))][:3]
Out[25]: 
                B1      B2      B3      B4      B5      B6      B7      B8      B9     B10     B11     B12     B13     B14     B15     B16     B17     B18     B19     B20      A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A6      A7      A8      A9     A10     A11     A12     A13     A14     A15     A16     A17     A18     A19     A20
TT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
2510203606  404800  404700  404600  404500  404400  404300  404200  404100  404000  403900  403800  403700  403600  403500  403400  403300  403200  403100  403000  402900  404900  405000  405100  405200  405300  405400  405500  405600  405700  405800  405900  406000  406100  406200  406300  406400  406500  406600  406700  406800
2510203606  404800  404700  404600  404500  404400  404300  404200  404100  404000  403900  403800  403700  403600  403500  403400  403300  403200  403100  403000  402900  404900  405000  405100  405200  405300  405400  405500  405600  405700  405800  405900  406000  406100  406200  406300  406400  406500  406600  406700  406800
2510203606  404800  404700  404600  404500  404400  404300  404200  404100  404000  403900  403800  403700  403600  403500  403400  403300  403200  403100  403000  402900  404900  405000  405100  405200  405300  405400  405500  405600  405700  405800  405900  406000  406100  406200  406300  406400  406500  406600  406700  406800
```

DF2 :-

```
[26]: miliSecDF.iloc[:,list(range(2, 81, 2))][:3]
Out[26]: 
            BQ1   BQ2   BQ3   BQ4   BQ5   BQ6   BQ7   BQ8   BQ9  BQ10  BQ11  BQ12  BQ13  BQ14  BQ15  BQ16  BQ17  BQ18  BQ19  BQ20  AQ1   AQ2   AQ3   AQ4   AQ5   AQ6   AQ7   AQ8   AQ9  AQ10  AQ11  AQ12  AQ13  AQ14  AQ15  AQ16  AQ17  AQ18  AQ19  AQ20
TT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
2510203606  500  2000  2000  9000  1500  3500  2000  2500  2750  1750   750  1250  1000  2750  1250  1000  1750  3250  3250   750  500  3500  2750  3500  3500  2250  1750  1750  1750  3000  3250  6000  2000  2000  1000  1500   500   750   250  1500
2510203606  500  2000  2000  9000  1500  3500  2000  2750  2750  1750   750  1250  1000  2750  1250  1000  1750  3250  3250   750  500  3500  2750  3500  3500  2250  1750  1750  1750  3000  3250  6000  2000  2000  1000  1500   500   750   250  1500
2510203606  500  2000  2000  9000  1500  3500  2000  2750  2750  1750   750  1250  1000  2750  1250  1000  1750  3250  3250   750  500  3500  2750  3500  3250  2500  1750  1750  1750  3000  3250  6000  2000  2000  1000  1500   500   750   250  1500
```

I need to use columns B1..(40 columns) as index for DF3 and add corresponding value from DF2. If value is missing then 0.

Expected Output :-

```
404800 500 500   500
404700 500 2000  2000
404600 500 2000  2000
404500
```

-Arpit

Comment: Use `df = pd.concat([DF1, DF2], axis=1)`

Comment: @jezrael, In DF3 values from DF1 become index and it might be having missing values.

Comment: So you need `s = pd.Series(DF2['col'], index=DF1['col'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael, I have 40 columns in DF1 & DF2.

Comment: So maybe not understand question, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @jezrael, I just edited the question.. please have a look.

Comment: hmmm, is possible create 3-4 columns for each and add expected output?

Comment: Thank you for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So it means there are same values for index? And same values per columns?

Comment: Ot is is not [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Why is for expcted output for second row `404700 500 2000  2000` ?

Comment: We can ignore index.. In expected output first column will be index (which will come from DF1 (with range max, min value of dataframe)) corresponding values @ DF2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200897/discussion-between-arpit-and-jezrael).

Comment: it's value of B2 column.